# Collection WhereIn method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying filtered a collection, but the code in the last row does not work. In this row the `$property->county_id` is an `integer`, the `params.county_id` is an `array`. I would like know the `array` contains the `integer`.

I think the code is wrong, because the key (maybe) must be the `params.county_id`. How I can do this?

Thanks the answers.

```
$buyerSearches = collect($items);

$result = $buyerSearches
            ->where('params.type', '=', $property->type)
            ->where('params.sale_type', '=', $property->sale_type)
            ->whereIn('params.contract_type', ['all', $property->contract_type])
            ->where('params.min_price', '<=', $property->price)
            ->where('params.max_price', '>=', $property->price)
            ->whereIn($property->county_id, 'params.county_id');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved, it works :)

```
$result = $buyerSearches
    ->where('params.type', '=', $property->type)
    ->where('params.sale_type', '=', $property->sale_type)
    ->whereIn('params.contract_type', ['all', $property->contract_type])
    ->where('params.min_price', '<=', $property->price)
    ->where('params.max_price', '>=', $property->price)
    ->filter(function($buyerSearch) use ($property) {
        return in_array($property->county_id, $buyerSearch['params']['county_id']);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the second argument in the whereIn is an array or create that array before the $result query and use it next.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead :

```
->whereIn('county_id', 'params.county_id');
```

Comment: $buyerSearches :

Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1765
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "id" => 1
      "params" => array:26 [
       ...        
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "id" => 2
      "params" => array:26 [
        ...
      ]
    ]
  ]
}